# How to perform the linux equivalent of "cp -r" in python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, file-copying

How to recursively copy directories (`cp -r`) in Python?

[os.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) results in `FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists:`.

And [distutils.dir_util.copy_tree](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree) raises `AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'dir_util'`

How to perform the linux equivalent on `cp -r` in Python?

Comment: One way to do using subprocess is:
`import subprocess`
`subprocess.call('cp -r source destination', shell=True)`

Comment: `system("cp -r")`   may suit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `distutils`, you may want to import like this if you notice the `AttributeError`:

```
import distutils
from distutils import dir_util
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree("sourceDir", "dstDir")
```

Alternatively, you can use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cp -r sourceDir dstDir', shell=True)
```